# closing dropdown menu after clicking on a menu item

Tags: javascript, jquery

when i click on a button a menu dropdown appears with menu items within. Currently when i click on a menu item the page changes to the clicked content but the menu list still appear and doesn't go away after clicking on a menu item. What do i need to add to my script so that after clicking on any of the menu items the menu would close.

menu button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-navbar collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
    </button>


<div class="nav-collapse collapse" style="height: 0px;">
        <ul id="Menu" data-bind="template: { name: 'menuItems', foreach: menuItemList, as: 'menuItem' }" class="nav">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

this is the script when clicking on a menu item:

```
<script type="text/html" id="menuItems">
    <li class="dropdown" data-bind="css: { active: isActive }">
        <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-bind="text: title, attr: { href: url }">
        </a>
    </li>
</script>
```

Comment: is there a good reason to use text/html script instead of Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of doing what you're doing, I would recommend utilizing javascript to achieve a DDL list with UL's and LI elements.

```js
var _ddls = $(".DropDownList");

_ddls.click(function() {
   $(this).children().slideUp();
});

_ddls.hover(function() {
    $(this).children().slideDown();
}, function() {
    $(this).children().slideUp();
});
```

```css
.DropDownList {
    list-style:none;
}

.DropDownList li
{
    display:none;
}

#ddl_example
{
    background-color:red;
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="ddl_example" class='DropDownList'>Menu
    <li id='option1'><a href='javascript:void()'>Option 1</a></li>
    <li id='option2'><a href='javascript:void()'>Option 2</a></li>
    <li id='option3'><a href='javascript:void()'>Option 3</a></li>
    <li id='option4'><a href='javascript:void()'>Option 4</a></li>
    <li id='option5'><a href='javascript:void()'>Option 5</a></li>
    <li id='option6'><a href='javascript:void()'>Option 6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: i noticed that after i click on one of the options the menu doesn't collapse and stays open - i would like for it to collapse after clicking on an option